# Nginx sub domain server block not matching

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I've mainly used Nginx as a reverse proxy for several years. I've created several subdomain server blocks used for proxying without issues. All of a sudden have a need to serve files from a local directory, and I cannot seem to match sub.www.example.com to serve files from that domain.

This is part of my default configuration file slightly modified for anonymity. In the snippet below, the www.example.com domain always hits when a browser is requesting www.example.com, and sub.www.example.com.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? Do you think there is there something outside of what I provided here a problem? If you need more configuration files, logs, or anything else; please ask.

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

      server_name www.example.com;
      proxy_cache www;

    location / {

      include   /etc/nginx/common_configs/locproxy.conf;

      proxy_pass http://www3;
      proxy_redirect http://www3 http://$server_name;
     }

        include   /etc/nginx/common_configs/hiddenfiles_loc.conf;

    deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; }

        include /etc/nginx/common_configs/http_to_https_redirects.conf;
}

server {
           listen 80;
           listen [::]:80;
           server_name sub.www.example.com;
           access_log  /var/log/nginx/sub.access.log;
           error_log  /var/log/nginx/sub.error.log debug;
           include   /etc/nginx/common_configs/hiddenfiles_loc.conf;
           location / {
              root /var/www/example;
              #log_not_found off;
              autoindex            off;
              index                index.html;
              try_files            $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
}

#Redirect example.com to www.example.com
server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

When I request a url for http://sub.www.example.com, I recieve content from www.example.com instead. Logs for www.example.com show activity, logs for sub.www.example.com show nothing. The log for www.example.com also show the request to sub.www.example.com.

The configuration above is in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file. What is really strange, is the redirect at the end of the configuration works.

A few www.example.com logs are posted below:

```
10.23.128.17 - - [14/Nov/2016:19:13:51 -0700] "GET /wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4e05f26752784196aa8fb9e77ae9ff08 HTTP/1.1" 200 3865 "http://sub.www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"

10.23.128.17 - - [14/Nov/2016:19:13:51 -0700] "GET /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/css/buddypress.min.css?ver=2.7.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 6378 "http://sub.www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"

10.23.128.17 - - [14/Nov/2016:19:13:51 -0700] "GET /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-core/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=2.7.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 460 "http://sub.www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
```

Now that I think about it, I should also add that I have something like 20 ssl subdomians on port 443 all working perfectly fine. Other than the redirect at the end to forward example.com to www.example.com, I think this is probably the first non-ssl port 80 sub domain I attempted to add to this server.

Does anybody spot a problem in this config, or can you think of someplace else I can look?

Comment: Please describe your problem more fully. What happens when you try to access the subdomain? Does it time out or is the wrong content displayed? What do the error and access logs say?

Comment: When I type http://sub.www.example.com in a web browser, I receive content from www.example.com instead of from sub.www.example.com. Logs show my activity as hitting www.example.com.

Comment: Logs for www.example.com show the request for sub.www.example.com; I'll post some logs in a minute.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more detail.

Comment: Talking to you about this, I realized more important details I could add. First, there is a redirect at the end that works. I've been using this server for several years, but other than the redirect from example.com to www.example.com at the end, I think this is the first time I have ever attempted to setup a sub-domain that is not ssl. May or may not be relevant info, I don't know.

Comment: Download my example configs, links at the end of this comments. Tidy up your listen directives, they're untidy but probably not a problem. In general as long as your server_name actually matches the subdomain properly it looks generally ok - but note you have sub.www.domain.com not sub.domain.com in there. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/#wpmu-nginx-configuration-files

Comment: I know the subdomain I'm using is probably odd, I didn't think about that much. But there is a good reason I'm using sub domains of www, and I actually wanted sub.www.domain.com, not sub.domain.com. I'll look at your example configs! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I simply have an organizational problem, then. Maybe the problem is somewhere else, I'll just need to go through it all and tidy it up, like you said. Thank you very much for the link to your files, the notes in your config are more than helpful! I will definitely use them to clean up my configurations, and probably understand my system better!

Comment: A simple typo could be the problem. You've configured it as sub.www.domain.com and you're probably typing sub.domain.com into your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a dns server entry pointing all subdomains of www to another server. The other server caused some things to work, and some to not work.

Thanks to Tim, I cleaned up all of my configurations, and ruled out these configs as a source of the problem.